# connecting two Activities

Tags: android

I have tried to link 3 xml pages namely, main.xml, form2.xml, pers.xml which have the class files ProjectActivity.java,Form2.java,personal.java.
I linked from ProjectActivity to Form2 using the following codes:

```
Intent i=new Intent(ProjectActivity.this,Form2.class);    
startActivity(i);   
finish();
```

And linked the Form2.java to personal.java by using the following coding :

```
Intent ns=new Intent(Form2.this,personal.class);   
startActivity(ns);   
finish();
```

The AndroidManifest.xml coding changed as follows : (Two  tags are added)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
    package="proj.m.billing"    
    android:versionCode="1"    
    android:versionName="1.0" >    
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />    
    <application    
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"    
        android:label="@string/app_name" >    
        <activity    
            android:name=".ProjectActivity"    
            android:label="@string/app_name" >    
            <intent-filter>    
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />    
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />    
            </intent-filter>    
        </activity>    
        <activity android:name=".Form2"></activity>    
        <activity android:name=".personal"></activity>    
    </application>    
</manifest>
```

While executing the program 'Forced to close' message has displayed, but no error detected.
Is there any problem in the AndroidManifest.xml or 'Intent' command..?

Comment: You should take a look at Logcat in eclipse, there should be an stacktrace that points out the problem.

Comment: no error seems here.see your logcat.there must be some exception message

Comment: Code seems proprer will u put up u r LogCat Output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- depend on manifest, all activity must be on main package name ( proj.m.billing.Form2 ,...)
- in one of your activity has some casting error.
- you must have errors on logcat but you not see that probably
- use java convention for naming ( not problem ) but recommended. change personal->PersonalActivity
- remove extra codes from activities and test again